# Can I calculate and check java project code coverage through Maven?

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven-2, code-coverage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Cobertura to fail M2 build for low code coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196721/how-to-get-cobertura-to-fail-m2-build-for-low-code-coverage)

I would like to calculate code coverage of my Java code base and fail building process if any package, class, or method has code coverage of 80% or less. Is it possible to achieve with some open source tool? Preferably through a maven2 plugin.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196721/how-to-get-cobertura-to-fail-m2-build-for-low-code-coverage

Comment: Yes, exactly, this is a duplicate, my fault

Comment: com, please close the question if it is a duplicate. It helps avoid multiple questions and answers on a single topic.

Comment: @Vineet, I've just voted for its closing..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Cobertura [cobertura-maven-plugin](http://mojohaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/)?